# Authenticated webpages ( via php/html + .htaccess) can’t see assets in other directories (css, JavaScript, images etc )

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, password-protection

I’m looking to password protect my entire site directory with HTML forms + PHP. I am able to capture an authenticated session and navigate between the pages with help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978761/custom-login-with-htaccess-through-html-php%22this%20post%22) (Thank you!) - however any external files that are linked in those pages are not visible to the browser. [Here's a reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFD5T.png)

---

**The Problem**

index page renders but without any assets ( css, js, images, fonts, etc; )

---

**Directory**

Everything is at the root directory.

```
├── pages
|   ├── page-1.html
|   └── page-2.html
|   └── page-3.html
├── assets
|   ├── main.css
|   └── all.js
├── .htaccess
├── login.php
└── index.html
```

---

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !login.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* login.php?file=$0 [QSA,L] # pass everything thru php
```

---

**login.php**

```
 <?php
 $file = 'index.html';
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $key = 'password';
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($password === $key){
      $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        readfile($file);

      die();
    } {
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>wrong password.</div>";
    }
  }
?>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Login</title>
   </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="pwd">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/assets/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>A title</title>

</head>
<body>
    A list of links
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/pages/page-1.html">page-1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/pages/page-2.html">page-2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/pages/page-3.html">page-3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script src="/assets/all.js" ></script>
</html>
```

I suspect that assets is not accessible because they are still private. Perhaps the solution is to allow access to not just index file?

I have zero experience in writing server side script like PHP so please bear with me if the answer to this question is really obvious. Thank you so much in advance!!